# Matrices of forms seen as sections of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Given a vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ , what are the sections of $\Omega^p(\operatorname{End} E)$? are they just matrices whose entries are $p$-forms?

Comment: Yes, basically. Or you can think of it as $\Omega^p \otimes E \otimes E^*$ if you prefer.

Comment: If you write End E in $\TeX$, you'll see $End E$, with no space between. If you write \operatorname{End}E, you'll see $\operatorname{End}E$, with proper spacing and "$\operatorname{End}$" properly non-italicized. (I fixed it.)  (I see that \operatorname{End}E appears above with $E$ on the next line, so you can't see the lack of space in the code.  But it's there.)